# Велика чи мала літера: (І/і)нтернет, (І/і)нтернет-магазин, (І/і)нтернет-з'єднання?

Tags: терміни, велика-мала-літера

Англійською мовою *[the Internet](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Internet)* (в тому значенні, в якому ми вживаємо це слово в українській мові) пишеться з великої літери.
<sub>Також є англійське слово *[internet](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/internet)* (з малої) — але воно має інше (ширше) значення: це будь-яке об'єднання комп'ютерних мереж, не обов'язково глобальне. Наприклад, об'єднання декількох офісних і домашніх мереж в одну надмережу (інтермережу) — це *internet* (але не *the Internet*).</sub>

Хоча назвати *the Internet* просто *іnternet*'ом не є помилкою (бо *іnternet* є гіперонімом до *the Internet*), і все частіше в британські видання (наприклад, BBC та Times) так роблять.

В українській мові слово *Інтернет*/*інтернет* не має значення просто (не обов'язково глобального) об'єднання мереж (наприклад, не можна сказати: «ми у своїй фірмі створили інтернет між відділами»). З іншого боку, воно часто вживається для позначення не самої глобальної мережі, а лише можливості взаємодіяти з нею («він лагодить інтернет», «в тебе інтернет є/працює?» — очевидно, що це про сполучення, а не про саму глобальну мережу, яка й не ламалася).

Отже в українській мові:

1. Як треба писати *Інтернет*/*інтернет* — з великої, з малої чи співіснують обидва варіанти?
2. Чи залежить це від відтінку значення? Чи різниться написання першої половини в складному слові від окремого слова?
3. В якому випадку написати з малої буде помилкою? В якому — написати з великої буде помилкою?

Comment: Я читав був, але не пам'ятаю у кого (здається у О. Пономарева [?] — але не можу відшукати зараз), що інтернет слід писати з маленької, оскільки, ця річ стійко увійшла в наше життя, як телеграф (чи пошта) в свій час, але зараз ж ніхто не пише телеграф з великої.

Comment: Можна також використовувати **всемережжя**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Також для додаткової інформації можна прочитати статтю [Сергія Чемеркіна](http://dspace.nbuv.gov.ua/bitstream/handle/123456789/37189/18-Chemerkin.pdf?sequence=1),де автор збірно подає  аргументи на користь вживання малої/великої літери у слові "**Інтернет**":

> -Основні аргументи на користь уживання ***великої*** літери у слові **"Інтернет"**:
>
> 1) В ["Українському правописі"](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/pravopys2015.htm) не зазаначено як писати це слово, оскільки, при   перших його виданнях, це поняття( 1990-х рр) не було актуалізованим. Але у "Правописі" зазаначено,що перше слово у назвах організацій завжди писатиметься з великої літери. Лексикографічні 
>   праці дають таку дефініцію: «
>   ***Інтернет***
>    — всесвітня **а*соціація*** комп’ютерних мереж, інтегрована мережева «павутина», 
>   яка складається з різних комунікаційних мереж, об’єднаних у 
>   єдину логічну архітектуру». Тобто 
>   Інтернет
>    — це асоціація.
>   У словнику лексема 
>   ***асоціація***
>    має кілька значень, головні з 
>   яких: 1) ‘добровільне об’єднання осіб чи організацій для до-
>   сягнення  спільної  господарської,  політичної,  культурної  чи 
>   якої-небудь іншої мети; товариство, спілка’; 2) ‘сполучення, 
>   з’єднання чого-небудь в одне ціле’. Якщо вважати, що при тлу-
>   маченні значення слова 
>   Інтернет
>    лексема 
>   асоціація
>    ужита в 
>   першому значенні, то 
>   Інтернет
>   , безперечно, є назвою органі-
>   зації. Якщо ж у другому — то належність цієї структури до 
>   організації ще потрібно довести.
>
> ***Інтернет***
>     —  це  назва  унікального  конкретного 
>   об’єкта поряд із назвами інших унікальних об’єктів, які теж ви-
>   конують функцію об’єднування комп’ютерних мереж, напри-
>   клад, 
>   Фідонет
>   , 
>   Нетсукуку
>    тощо. Чи є слово 
>   Інтернет
>    власною 
>   назвою? Нагадаємо, *власна назва* — це іменник, що позначає 
>   слово або сполучення слів, яке використовують для називання 
>   конкретного, цілком визначеного предмета чи явища, виділя-
>   ючи цей предмет із розряду однотипних предметів чи явищ. 
>   Отже, слово 
>   **Інтернет**
>    — ***іменник, воно називає конкретне яви-
>   ще і вирізняється з-поміж інших однотипних явищ (мереж із 
>   назвами 
>   *Фідонет*
>   , 
>   *Нетсукуку* 
>   та ін.), тому є власною назвою, а 
>   відповідно його варто писати з великої літери***
>
> • Основні аргументи на користь уживання **малої** літери:
>
> В  українській  мові  постійно  відбувається  трансформація 
>   великої літери у малу при переході власної назви до розряду 
>   загальних. Чи набуло слово 
>   **Інтернет**
>    рис загальної назви? Під цим терміном розуміють 
>   глобальну інформаційну мережу, побудовану за певною техно-
>   логією, так само, як за певними технологіями побудовані радіо, 
>   телебачення та інші елементи інформаційного простору. Тому 
>   немає потреби виокремлювати у написанні з великої літери цю 
>   назву поряд із розрядами інших загальних назв — 
>   телефоном, 
>   радіо, телебаченням
>    тощо. Але ж поряд із 
>   Інтернетом
>    існують 
>   інші назви комп’ютерних мереж, наприклад, 
>   Фідонет
>   ! Однак,  порівнюва-
>   ти, наприклад, назви 
>   **Інтернет**
>    і 
>   *Фідонет*
>    у такому контексті не 
>   коректно, оскільки 
>   *Фідонет*
>    сьогодні — це комп’ютерна мережа, яка існує частково й завдяки мережі 
>   **Інтернет**
>   . Помітно, що 
>   слово 
>   **Інтернет**
>    втрачає риси власної назви, набуваючи ознак 
>   загальної, тобто 
>   **Інтернет**
>    — це певна комп’ютерна техноло-
>   гія, тому таке слово потрібно писати з **малої** літери.
>
> • 
>   Основні аргументи на користь уживання **двох літер**:
>
> Коли  ми  сьогодні  пишемо  чи  читаємо 
>   Надішли  файл  по 
>   **Інтернету**
>   ; 
>   Нам у будинок провели **Інтернет**
>   , то, ймовірно, ма-
>   ємо на увазі не «всесвітню асоціацію комп’ютерних мереж», 
>   як зазначено у словникові, а звичайнісіньку технологію пере-
>   давання/отримання інформації. У цьому разі нібито нелогічно 
>   писати назву технології з великої літери, адже слова, які по-
>   значають загальноприйняті технології, пишуть із малої літе-
>   ри — 
>   телеграф, метро, електрика
>   . А от у реченні 
>   У 1990-ті 
>   роки більшість комп’ютерних мереж були об’єднані в мережу 
>   **Інтернет**
>    зрозуміло, що, навпаки, йдеться не про технологію, а 
>   про мережу як комп’ютерну асоціацію. **Тобто слово 
>   **Інтернет**
>   має не одне значення. І відповідно до значення, вжитого у кон-
>   тексті, потрібно писати велику чи малу літеру в цьому слові.**

Є багато неоднозначних поглядів, щодо вирішення цього питання, але Сергій Чемеркін зазаначає:

> "...найвищій інституції з дослідження української мови знову доведеться
>   вирішувати це питання, а наразі слово 
>   **Інтернет** пишемо з **великої** літери"

.

Comment: Але я все одно «плюсанув» і прийняв цю відповідь, бо вважаю різнобічний огляд питання (що за посиланням) дуже цінним, чогось саме такого я й чекав. Сподіюваюсь Ви або хтось інший зможе пізніше перенести основні тези статті Сергія Чемеркіна прямо у відповідь. Тобто це щось типу прийняття відповіді «авансом». (Можливо, я навіть сам пізніше відредагую цю відповідь, переказавши основні моменти тексту за посиланням — якщо Ви не зробите цього раніше і не будете проти, щоб хтось інший це зробив за Вас.)

Comment: Дякую за заувагу .Врахувала побажання.

Answer (score 6):

Слово *інтернет* [потрібно писати](http://ukraine.velesava.com/?p=183) з великої літери в тому випадку, коли мова йде про комп'ютерну мережу "Internet", що була створена в 60-х роках в межах одного з проектів Міністерства оборони США. Це була одна з багатьох створених тоді мереж, кожна з яких мала своє власне ім’я. Мережі "Інтернет" судилося стати загальним стандартом, тому її власна назва стала загальною. А загальна назва технології має писатись з маленької літери.

Ще приклади подібного перетворення власної назви на загальну: *аспірін*, *термос*, *памперс*, *вазелін*, *рентген*, *вінчестер*, *кондом*, *прімус*, *скотч*. Всі ці слова пишуться з маленької літери в усіх випадках, окрім тих, коли мається на увазі конкретна торгова марка або прізвище винахідника.

<sub>Монгольською мовою *ксерокс* буде *кенон*. Тому що ксерокси марки «Canon» з’явились в Монголії першими.</sub>

Інше [джерело](http://ukraine.velesava.com/?p=183) стверджує, що можна писати і з великої літери, і з малої.

Інтернет може вживатися як іменник (самостійна частина мови) або як перша частина складних слів. Від цього залежить написання.

При самостійному вживанні зараз можливе написання з великої та малої літери: *доступ до Інтернету* та *доступ до інтернету*, *користуватися Інтернетом* та *користуватися інтернетом*.

При вживанні як першої частини складних слів правильно тільки з малої і через дефіс: *інтернет-сайт*, *інтернет-користувач*, *інтернет-олімпіада*, *інтернет-залежний*.

Таке написання встановлено в 4-му виданні «Русского орфографического словаря» РАН, М., 2012 (посилаємося на це російське видання, тому що в Україні подібна робота не проводиться).

<sub>**Як писали раніше?**</sub>

<sub>У попередніх виданнях «Русского орфографического словаря» проводився чіткий поділ: інтернет – як перша частина складних слів – тільки з маленької літери, як і зараз (інтернет-сайт), а от Інтернет при самостійному вживанні – тільки з великої літери (доступ до Інтернету), варіантів написання цього слова з малої літери при самостійному вживанні не було. Але в 4-му виданні «Русского орфографического словаря» РАН «для слова інтернет, згідно з практикою написання і рішенням Орфографічної комісії РАН, запропоновано два варіанти – з великої і з малої літери» (цитата з передмови до 4-го видання).</sub>

Словник-довідник ["Велика чи мала літера"](http://velyka-chy-mala-litera.wikidot.com/i) Жайворонка, який вийшов під грифом НАН, а отже, є нормативним, підтримує велику літеру в цьому слові. Проте там не вказаний контекст, в якому слово вживається.

P.S. *Рунет* потрібно писати з великої: *Премія Рунета*.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55578/discussion-on-answer-by-sashaeve--------).

Comment: Оскільки я не розумію одного з найперших тверджень цієї відповіді і не зміг добитися роз'яснень у попередніх коментарях, то я врешті-решт поставлю мінус.

Answer (score 4):

*інтернет-магазин, інтернет-з'єднання, інтернет-провайдер* — складні іменники, тут однозначно з малої літери.

*Інтернет* — [«Словники України on-line» від УМІФ](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) дають з великої, але узус різниться, вживається і з великої, і з малої.

Comment: Ну, а чи є «інтернет» з малої неправильним? Чи є випадки, коли неможна написати «Інтернет», а лише «інтернет» (окрім перщої частини в складних словах, звісно)? Те, що Ви написали — **дуже правильно**, але поки що не виглядає повною відповіддю.

Comment: Хоча, звісно, краще чітко висловити лише те, що знаєш — ніж написати щось не зовсім правильне про те, чого не знаєш.

Comment: Принаймні, поки що Ваша відповідь мені подобається все ж більше ніж інша — бо вона, хоч і неповна, але чітка і не містить, на мою думку, жодних протиріч.

Comment: Судячи з пояснень щодо видалення моїх інших відповідей, ця спільнота намагається гратися в чергову вікіпедію чи вузькопрофільний форум, вимагаючи виключно вичерпних відповідей з купою посилань на всі доступні джерела незалежно від того, чи запитувачу потрібна проста відповідь на просте питання, чи він збирається писати наукову статтю на тему. При тому, що іншомовні лінгвістичні спільноти як тут, так і на інших майданчиках містять нормальне живе обговорення варіантів перекладу чи граматичних явищ та добір найбільш прийнятних/правильних варіантів засобами оцінювання відповідей-коментарів.

Comment: На жаль, Ваша правда :(. Мені дуже подобається прагнення до обґрунтованих відповідей учасників цієї спільноти, але дуже **не** подобається наполегливість, з якою деякі учасники вимагають ідеальних дописів від інших. Але я не думаю, що можу зараз щось змінити; на разі єдине, що я можу, це попросити Вас не полишати цю спільноту назовсім, бо інакше ймовірність перехилити терези суспільної думки в інший бік (у бік поблажливості до дописів з боку вимогливості) ще зменшиться.

Answer (score 2):

На додаток до відповіді sashaeve наведу переклад уривка з книги *TCP/IP Illustrated* за авторством *W. Richard Stevens*:

> Слово інтернет має різні значення в залежності від того велика чи
>   маленька перша літера.
>
> Маленька перша літера значить декілька мереж сполучених спільним
>   протоколом. Велика перша літера позначає множину хостів по всьому
>   світу (понад мільйон), які зв'язуються один з одним за допомогою
>   TCP/IP. Хоча Інтернет - це інтернет, зворотнє твердження не
>   виконується.

Книзі вже багато років, на сьогодні кількість хосів в Інтернеті [більш ніж мільярд.](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8E_%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%96%D0%B2)

Comment: Так, я про це писав в тексті самого запитання. Але це дійсно для англійської мови. Чи справджується це української, ось у чому питання.